# What are the quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_2$?

Tags: galois-theory, p-adic-number-theory

How do you classify the non-squares in $\mathbb{Q}_2$? I've tried writing down expansions for "odd" numbers in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, but unlike in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, the n$^{th}$ term in the expansion is not always uniquely determined once you know the first n-1 terms, and when you come across a non-square it's not obvious (to me at least) whether it is divisible by another non-square you've already found.

Comment: There are seven distinct quadratic extensions of $\mathbb Q_2$. My book does not give a proof of this, but references Serre's *A Course in Arithmetic*.

Comment: Aren't the squares things of the form $4^m (1 + 8n)$, for integers $m$ and 2-adic integers $n$?

Comment: Ah, now I think I know what you were trying to describe. Try working with more digits of precision when solving. Or just use Newton's method to compute square roots.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765119

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As for any field $K$ of characteristic different from $2$, the quadratic extensions are all of the form $K(\sqrt{d})$ for $d \in K^{\times} \setminus K^{\times 2}$; moreover $K(\sqrt{d_1}) \cong K(\sqrt{d_2}) \iff d_1 = a^2 d_2$.  Thus they are parameterized by the nontrivial elements of $K^{\times}/K^{\times 2}$, it is then sufficient to understand this quotient.  Note that this is an $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space, so it's enough to determine its dimension.  In what follows I will denote this $\mathbb{F}_2$-dimension simply by "$\operatorname{dim}$".

If $K$ is the fraction field of a discrete valuation ring $R$, then from $K^{\times} \cong R^{\times} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ it is easy to see that

$\dim K^{\times}/K^{\times 2} =  1+ \dim R^{\times}/R^{\times 2}$.

So, here, you want to know the square classes in $\mathbb{Z}_2^{\times}$.  I claim that an element $u \in \mathbb{Z}_2^{\times}$ is a square iff its residue modulo $8$ is a square in $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$: to see this, use Hensel's Lemma.  From this it follows that

$\dim \mathbb{Z}_2^{\times} / \mathbb{Z}_2^{\times 2} = \dim (\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^{\times} / (\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^{\times 2} = 2$

and thus

$\dim \mathbb{Q}_2^{\times} / \mathbb{Q}_2^{\times 2} = 3$.

This argument should give you explicit representatives as well: that is, the $2^3-1 = 7$ quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_2$ are gotten by adjoining square roots of $3,5,7,2,6,10,14$.

Comment: Thanks. I knew Hensel's lemma was lurking in there somewhere.

Comment: @Pete L. Clark, why this is $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space and why                    $ dim (\mathbb{Z}/ 8 \mathbb{Z})$ / $(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^2=2$ ?