# Ramified extension of local field which is not Galois

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-field

Unramified extension of local field is automatically galois because there is bijection between unramified extension of local field and extension of residue finite field, that is galois.

But, what about ramified extension of local field ?
**Does every ramified extension of local field is galois** ?

Comment: Do you know any example of such extension ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'such' ? My question is asking whether there is an example of titled one. If you mean some extension of ramified extension of local field, then, $ \Bbb{Q_p}(p^{1/n},μ_{p^m-1})$ is ramified index is  $m$ and residue index is $n$ over $ \Bbb{Q_p}$.

Comment: What about $\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt[p]p)$?

Comment: Also... every unramified extension of local fields is Galois. So if every ramified extension was Galois too, then all extensions would be Galois!

Comment: I think by "such extensions" reuns means ramified extensions, and what he means is that in fact, "most" ramified extensions are *not* Galois. That is, if you tried out a few of degree 3 or bigger, you should have stumbled upon a non-Galois one. In fact, generalizing @Mathmo123 's comment, it was shown in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4256962/96384 that $\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt[n]{p})$ is Galois only if $n$ divides $p-1$, or $n=p=2$.

Comment: Just to sharpen my point a bit: every non-Galois extension of local fields is ramified. So just find any non-Galois extension of local fields. Radical extensions are a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, at least as a placeholder, when $\mathbb Q_p$ contains no $n$th root of unity, then "the" extension $\mathbb Q_p(p^{1/n})$ is not Galois. It is of degree $n$, by Eisenstein's criterion, but is not "normal", because it is missing $n$th roots of unity, etc.

I would think that more complicated extensions would tend to have this property, as well, so this is not any sort of pathology.